How to implement TS code connection.onLogs monitoring in Rust
enter image description here
I want to implement the watchRaydiumV4Initialize2Logs method, so I need to find something similar to connection.onLogs in Rust, but the RpcClient struct in solana-client does not implement a method similar to this.
So I want to find such an implementation

Please provide all of the details of your question in text format, not as a screenshot. Text in screenshots cannot be searched and are therefore unlikely to be useful to future users asking the same question.

You need to call logssubscribe using solana_ws:

https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/logssubscribe
https://docs.rs/solana-ws/latest/solana_ws/

There is an example on GitHub:
    /// Subscribe to transaction log events.
    ///
    /// Receives messages of type [`RpcLogsResponse`] when a transaction is committed.
    ///
    /// # RPC Reference
    ///
    /// This method corresponds directly to the [`logsSubscribe`] RPC method.
    ///
    /// [`logsSubscribe`]: https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#logssubscribe
    pub async fn logs_subscribe<F>(
        &self,
        filter: RpcTransactionLogsFilter,
        config: RpcTransactionLogsConfig,
        cb: F,
    ) -> SubscriptionId
    where
        F: Fn(WithContext<RpcLogsResponse>) + Send + 'static,
    {
        self.ws
            .add_listener("logsSubscribe", Some(json!([filter, config])), cb)
            .await
    }



Thank you so much, I've solved this problem

Please accept the answer if it solved your problem
